# Discriminated Union - Allow Pattern Matching but Restrict Construction

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I have an F# Discriminated Union, where I want to apply some "constructor logic" to any values used in constructing the union cases.  Let's say the union looks like this:

```
type ValidValue =
| ValidInt of int
| ValidString of string
// other cases, etc.
```

Now, I want to apply some logic to the values that are actually passed-in to ensure that they are valid.  In order to make sure I don't end up dealing with `ValidValue` instances that aren't really valid (haven't been constructed using the validation logic), I make the constructors private and expose a public function that enforces my logic to construct them.

```
type ValidValue = 
    private
    | ValidInt of int
    | ValidString of string

module ValidValue =
    let createInt value =
        if value > 0 // Here's some validation logic
        then Ok <| ValidInt value
        else Error "Integer values must be positive"

    let createString value =
        if value |> String.length > 0 // More validation logic
        then Ok <| ValidString value
        else Error "String values must not be empty"
```

This works, allowing me to enforce the validation logic and make sure every instance of `ValidValue` really is valid.  However, the problem is that no one outside of this module can pattern-match on `ValidValue` to inspect the  result, limiting the usefulness of the Discriminated Union.

I would like to allow outside users to still pattern-match and work with the `ValidValue` like any other DU, but that's not possible if it has a private constructor.  The only solution I can think of would be to wrap each value inside the DU in a single-case union type with a private constructor, and leave the actual `ValidValue` constructors public.  This would expose the cases to the outside, allowing them to be matched against, but still mostly-prevent the outside caller from constructing them, because the values required to instantiate each case would have private constructors:

```
type VInt = private VInt of int
type VString = private VString of string

type ValidValue = 
| ValidInt of VInt
| ValidString of VString

module ValidValue =
    let createInt value =
        if value > 0 // Here's some validation logic
        then Ok <| ValidInt (VInt value)
        else Error "Integer values must be positive"

    let createString value =
        if value |> String.length > 0 // More validation logic
        then Ok <| ValidString (VString value)
        else Error "String values must not be empty"
```

Now the caller can match against the cases of `ValidValue`, but they can't read the actual integer and string values inside the union cases, because they're wrapped in types that have private constructors.  This can be fixed with `value` functions for each type:

```
module VInt =
    let value (VInt i) = i

module VString =
    let value (VString s) = s
```

Unfortunately, now the burden on the caller is increased:

```
// Example Caller
let result = ValidValue.createInt 3

match result with
| Ok validValue ->
    match validValue with
    | ValidInt vi ->
        let i = vi |> VInt.value // Caller always needs this extra line
        printfn "Int: %d" i
    | ValidString vs ->
        let s = vs |> VString.value // Can't use the value directly
        printfn "String: %s" s
| Error error ->
    printfn "Invalid: %s" error
```

Is there a better way to enforce the execution of the constructor logic I wanted at the beginning, without increasing the burden somewhere else down the line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have private case constructors but expose public active patterns with the same names. Here's how you would define and use them (creation functions omitted for brevity):

```
module Helpers =
    type ValidValue = 
        private
        | ValidInt of int
        | ValidString of string

    let (|ValidInt|ValidString|) = function
        | ValidValue.ValidInt i -> ValidInt i
        | ValidValue.ValidString s -> ValidString s

module Usage =
    open Helpers

    let validValueToString = function
        | ValidInt i -> string i
        | ValidString s -> s
    //  Easy to use ✔

    // Let's try to make our own ValidInt 
    ValidInt -1
    // error FS1093: The union cases or fields of the type
    // 'ValidValue' are not accessible from this code location
    //  Blocked by the compiler ✔
```

Comment: I saw a Haskell answer like this, using View Patterns, and it does seem like a possible middle-ground.  The only thing I don't like about it is that the Active Patterns won't enforce exhaustive matching on the cases, so it would be possible for bugs to slip in if new union cases were added or developers didn't know about all the possible Active Patterns.  Still, this may be the best we can do given the constraints of the language.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach Actually, this is a complete active pattern so you do get exhaustiveness checking. It's partial active patterns where you don't. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns)

Comment: Unfortunately, when I actually tried to implement this solution, I got the error `Active Patterns cannot return more than 7 possibilities`.  I believe this is because my DU has 16 cases.  Any ideas on how to work through this?

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach I've never heard of that limitation! It seems quite arbitrary  Unfortunately, I don't know a workaround, other than splitting your types into smaller types with 7 or less subtypes. Going back to your original idea for a workaround, you could add `Value` member properties to `VInt` etc. so you can just write `vi.Value` instead of `vi |> VInt.value`

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a particular reason that a discriminated union is required, given the particular use case you've provided it sounds like you don't actually want a discriminated union at all since an active pattern would be more useful. For example:

```
let (|ValidInt|ValidString|Invalid|) (value:obj) = 
    match value with
    | :? int as x -> if x > 0 then ValidInt x else Invalid
    | :? string as x -> if x.Length > 0 then ValidString x else Invalid
    | _ -> Invalid
```

At that point, callers can match and be assured that the logic has been applied.

```
match someValue with
| ValidInt x -> // ...
| _ -> // ...
```

Comment: I don't think that provides all of the same benefits. It can be nice to have a constrained type so that any function receiving an instance gets a sort of type-level guarantee of certain properties of the data, and doesn't have to do any further checking/branching.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox I agree with you, however in many cases this type of quasi dependent type behavior tends to be used instead of validation. In the latter case you have no guarantee by the compiler since your input will come from the outside, e.g. form or database query, so you will go down with a run-time error....

Comment: @s952163 Even a database query can't put data into your constrained type without using code from your constrained type's module because of the private constructor. As long as you're confident that the validation in that one module is correct then you can make assumptions everywhere else. Of course it's only a soft guarantee because it relies on a function being implemented correctly.

Comment: My example is a simplified use-case.  I definitely want a discriminated union in my real scenario, as I am representing a fixed set of states, each with different rules around the values they contain.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox absolutely. I was alluding to the difference in compile time warnings/errors that makes sure your code works, and validation/error/exception handling that is necessary when you go into the non-pure world.